# Crossfade not working very well in slides.js

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am using some javascript to randomly swap out the background image of a slideshow on page load. It works except that i want to use crossfading along with fade.

```
//slideshow script   

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slides').slides({
  preload: true,
  preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif',
  play: 8000,
  pause: 2500,
  hoverPause: true,
  crossfade:true,
  effect:'fade',



  });
```

});

When I set crossfade to "true", the transparent .pngs in the slide div stop fading nicely; the next one in line fades in ok, but the previous one persists and then disappears (doesn't fade out). If I delete crossfade, it works ok but the client wants then to fade in and out of each other.

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aX7Gv/4/)

And [here the location of my site](http://design-scp.migcom.com/) home page where you can see the slider; (you need a user and password to see it, both are mig)

Comment: What I have found is if I put a background image in .slides_container div.slide, suddenly the crossfade works. But, that background image obscures the background image in the container div which is what i am having randomly swapped out with each page load. It's something about the fact that the slides contain transparent pngs with nothing in the background of the slide div that makes the crossfade fail. For client review, I had to take off crossfading (hoping they won't remember it used to do that) so if you go to the example link, it will just be fading currently. Any ideas anyone?